# Help understanding a question

Tags: calculus, taylor-expansion

I know this probably isn't the best question to post as far as further use with others, but I literally have no where else to turn to for study assistance. My problem is as follows:

> Find $T_5(x)$: Taylor polynomial of degree 5 of the function $f(x)=cos(x)$ at $a=0$

$T_5(x) = 1-\frac{x^2}{2!}+\frac{x^4}{4!}$

> Find all values of $x$ for which this opproximation is within $0.003406$ of the right answer. Assume for simplicity that we limit ourselves to $\big|x\big|\leq1$.

$\big|x\big|\leq$ answer

Its the second part that I am struggling to understand what it means. I literally have been at this one part for the past 30 minutes. All help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Have you used Taylor's theorem before?

Comment: $\frac{f(a)x^n}{n!}$? Of course. I'm sure something is just not clicking, but I am very familiar with it so far.

Comment: As in the part of Taylor's theorem allowing you to approximate the error of a finite Taylor Series expansion.

Answer (score 2):

No, you have to solve $\;\lvert T_5(x)-\cos x\rvert\le 0.003406$.

*Hint:* $\cos x$ is defined by an alternating series, so you have information on the error when you truncate the series at a given order.

Comment: So what you are saying is that I have this: $\big|((1-\frac{x^2}{2!}+\frac{x^4}{4!})-\frac{(-1)^n(x)^{2n}}{2n!})\big|\leq 0.003406$? I am uncertain where I would go from here, seeing as I have n's that would prevent me from solving for x.

Comment: I meant: $\big|((1-\frac{x^2}{2!}+\frac{x^4}{4!})-\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{(-1)^n(x)^{2n}}{2n!})\big|\leq 0.003406$

Answer (score 1):

For $|x|\leq1$, the Maclaurin series (of cos(x)) is an decreasing alternating series, so the error in your approximation will be no worse then the next non-zero term in the series, namely $|-\frac{x^{6}}{6!}|$. However you will want to review estimates for the remainder in a Taylor series. You will not always have this trick at your disposal.

Comment: Is what you are saying that I need to sum $T_5(x)$? If so, I don't know what to plug into x.